# Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean if i try to move to netty

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean

Getting above exception. I am trying to move to netty server which comes along with webflux. I have removed spring-boot-starter-web so that tomcat does not come along with it. Below is my main class:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("failed"+e);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `@SpringBootApplication` to your Main class. This tells Spring where the starting point is and without this Spring is unable to bootstrap your application.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("failed"+e);
    }
}
```